# Issue running glmnet() for mtcars dataset

Tags: r, function, syntax-error, glmnet, lasso-regression

Whenever I run `glmnet(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, alpha=1)` (from the `glmnet` package) I get the following error:

"Error in glmnet(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, alpha = 1) : unused argument (data = mtcars)"

Any ideas for how to deal with this?

I think its because the glmnet() function is supposed to take in x and y as separate arguments. If I need separate x and y arguments, how would I write the formula so that `glmnet::glmnet()` runs for all variables of `mtcars`?

Comment: That tutorial you linked to is about the `glmnetUtils` package while you are probably referring to the `glmnet` package.

Comment: @markus you're right - I have edited the question

Comment: Take a look at the docs (`?glmnet::glmnet`). It doesn't have a `data` argument; rather it takes a matrix `x` and a vector or matrix `y` for the response. The syntax you're using looks more like base functions such as `lm` that take formulas. Docs have several examples as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter suggests you need to use the `glmnet` method like so:

```
fit <- glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]), mtcars$mpg, alpha=1)

plot(fit)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer - could you interpret the plot for me? Just in general, but also, what does the x-axis represent?

Comment: The X-axis represents the absolute value of the sum of the model coefficients. LASSO works by adding a penalty to your regression loss function. This penalty is the absolute value of the coefficients. As you relax the penalty (make it larger) more variables come into the model. The coefficients of the variables is denoted by the y-axis.